# Generating constants with XmlBeans

Tags: xsd, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

We are using XmlBeans 2.6.0 to generate classes from `.xsd`. A complex type has an attribute

```
<xs:attribute name="WEB" use="optional" fixed="2" type="xs:int"/>
```

An earlier version based on Apache CXF generated from this stuff

```
public static final int WEB = 2;
```

Is it possible somehow to get the same result using XmlBeans?

**UPD** Source generation is performed with xmlbeans-maven-plugin 2.3.3.

Thanks in advance.